# Access data from the parent window in a child window in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have two windows (App.py and ChildApp.py) and .ui files for both with same name.

[image]

App.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
from ChildApp import ChildApp
qtCreatorFile = "App.ui" # Enter file here.
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)
class App(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.message = None
        self.child_window = ChildApp()
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.sendMessage)
    def sendMessage(self):
        self.message = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.child_window.show()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = App()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

ChildApp.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
qtCreatorFile = "ChildApp.ui" # Enter file here.
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)
class ChildApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.alertmessage)
    def alertmessage(self):
        message = "test"
        self.label.setText("Message : "+message)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ChildApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In Main.py file I have a variable `self.message`.
When I click on the button "Do something with text", text in the textbox is assigned to `self.message` and the child window is opened.

Now in the child window, when I click on button "Show message", the method `alertmessage()` is called, where it sets `message = "text"`.
This variable `message` must be assigned to value of `self.message` from MainApp.py.

Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Call the child that way:

```
    self.child_window = ChildApp(parent=self)
```

Define the child app this way:

```
class ChildApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
```

you can use the parent variables through `self.parent.whatever`

It must work, but I wouldn't advise this because you are not supposed to know the fields of the parent form the child.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get local data from the parent. I would do the following:

Use a signal to update the child when the text is changed in the `lineEdit`:

```
self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.updateChild)
```

Add this function in the main window:

```
def updateChild(self):
    self.child_window.setMessage(self.lineEdit.text())
```

and keep the variable `self._message` updated in the child window:

```
def setMessage(self, message):
    self._message=message
```

so that whenever you need this variable, it is up to date

Comment: I don't have the ".ui" that you are using, I have not tried this code, tell me if it helps

Comment: I am able to access variables from all child windows. but I want to access variables from the parent in all child windows

Comment: Simply update variables of each child window in the updateChild function. It can even be a loop over a list of windows. Does it work?

Comment: Or try to write "global message" at the beginning of each window, and use "message" variable instead of "self.message". Not sure either that they use a shared memory